# Fragment is not currently in the FragmentManager while notifying the viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I am facing a problem wile notifying the viewPager on new data set. 
I have two viewpager on same activity which i want to notify if there is any new data arrive

```
public class DetailActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    private ViewPager dishPager,restaurantPager;
    public DishPager dishPagerAdapter;
    public RestaurantPager restaurantPagerAdapter;
    public int dishPageNumber;
    ModelManager objModelManager;
    PersistentStoreHelper persistentStoreHelper;
    DishDetailPageModel objDetailPageModel;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("Broadcasting_from_DetailModel"));

        dishPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        restaurantPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerRest);
        dishPagerAdapter = new DishPager(getSupportFragmentManager());
        restaurantPagerAdapter = new RestaurantPager(getSupportFragmentManager());
        dishPager.setAdapter(dishPagerAdapter);
        restaurantPager.setAdapter(restaurantPagerAdapter);
       }
       private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        restaurantPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        dishPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
private class DishPager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
   public DishPager(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        dishPageNumber = //connected to model
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        String img = null;
        //data is a bundle loaded from the model
        return DishPagerFragment.create(data);
    }}
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dishPageNumber;
    }
   }
private class RestaurantPager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
   public DishPager(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        String img = null;
        //data is a bundle loaded from the model
        return RestaurantPagerFragment.create(data);
    }}
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }
   }
   }
```

I am calling this DetailActivity from my MainActivity on every listItemClick

The problem is when i load the DetailActivity for the first time it is running without any problem.
But second time when the DetailActivity loads it is creating the problem while notifying the viewpager.

I am getting the following error.

```
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment 

RestaurantPagerFragment{1e750466} is not currently in the FragmentManager
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentInstanceState(FragmentManager.java:599)
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.destroyItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:136)
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:874)
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2824)
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at com.hibrise.androidtomato.view.DetailActivity$1.onReceive(DetailActivity.java:130)
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-02 20:53:59.864: E/AndroidRuntime(14609):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Please solve the issue.
If you have any problem in understanding the question, please write a comment.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

may it help

```
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        if (((Fragment) object).isAdded()) {
            return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
        } else {
            return super.getItemPosition(object);
        }
    }
```